# Sending message, an instance of a player class, which can communicate with other playes

Tags: java, message

First of all sorry, for asking a question without displaying any ideas of mine on how to solve it.
I have a task as follows

```
Create 2 player instances
one player should send message to second player ("initiator player")
when a player recieves message it should reply with a message that contains the recieved message 
concatenated with counter of how many message this player already sent. And both players run in thesame process.
```

I have no clue on how to go about this, especially the idea of send message and replying the message.

Now, its suppose to be a purely java implementation without use of any frameworks , spring, websocket etc.

I also thought of the producer consumer approach, but i would like to get a simple explanation and may be a minimal working code on send and replying, I think what evades me is mode of communication, is this just a recursive send method and another get method (recieving)  this message

Answer (score 0):

Messaging is an abstract concept. Message can be considered as a portion of data that has to be emitted, transferred, received and processed in some way. It's not tied to particular programming language, framework or library. Besides of Spring, Websocket, JMS, etc messages are ubiquitous on low-level like Win32 API, D-Bus, networking.

As for your task, the message can be just a string. There is no need to represent it as JSON/XML/etc since both players run in the same process.

Original task description is quite broad. From my perspective, you **don't need recursion** but a kind of **pendulum**. The first player sends initialization message and waits for response. Meanwhile, the second player receives initialization message, adds his counter to the message and replies. Then the first player wakes up once response received, adds his counter and sends back. This exchange repeats again and again. Also, each player must not send next message before getting answer to the previous message.

[Blocking queues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is the best approach in pure Java within one process.

Consider the following code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class MessageTask
{
    // Blocking queue looks superfluous for single message. But such a queue saves us from cumbersome
    // synchronization of the threads.
    private static final int MAX_MESSAGES_IN_QUEUE = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BlockingQueue<String> firstToSecond = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(MAX_MESSAGES_IN_QUEUE);
        BlockingQueue<String> secondToFirst = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(MAX_MESSAGES_IN_QUEUE);

        // Both players use the same queues symmetrically.
        InitiatorPlayer firstPlayer = new InitiatorPlayer(firstToSecond, secondToFirst);
        Player secondPlayer = new Player(secondToFirst, firstToSecond);

        // Please note that we can start threads in reverse order. But thankfully to
        // blocking queues the second player will wait for initialization message from
        // the first player.
        new Thread(secondPlayer).start();
        new Thread(firstPlayer).start();
    }
}

class Player implements Runnable
{
    protected final BlockingQueue<String> sent;
    protected final BlockingQueue<String> received;

    // Please aware that integer field may overflow during prolonged run
    // of the program. So after 2147483647 we'll get -2147483648. We can
    // either use BigInteger or compare the field with Integer.MAX_VALUE
    // before each increment.
    //
    // Let's choose BigInteger for simplicity.
    private BigInteger numberOfMessagesSent = new BigInteger("0");

    public Player(BlockingQueue<String> sent, BlockingQueue<String> received)
    {
        this.sent = sent;
        this.received = received;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String receivedMessage = receive();
            reply(receivedMessage);
        }
    }

    protected String receive()
    {
        String receivedMessage;
        try
        {
            // Take message from the queue if available or wait otherwise.
            receivedMessage = received.take();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException interrupted)
        {
            String error = String.format(
                    "Player [%s] failed to receive message on iteration [%d].",
                    this, numberOfMessagesSent);
            throw new IllegalStateException(error, interrupted);
        }
        return receivedMessage;
    }

    protected void reply(String receivedMessage)
    {
        String reply = receivedMessage + " " + numberOfMessagesSent;
        try
        {
            // Send message if the queue is not full or wait until one message
            // can fit.
            sent.put(reply);
            System.out.printf("Player [%s] sent message [%s].%n", this, reply);
            numberOfMessagesSent = numberOfMessagesSent.add(BigInteger.ONE);

            // All players will work fine without this delay. It placed here just
            // for slowing the console output down.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException interrupted)
        {
            String error = String.format(
                    "Player [%s] failed to send message [%s] on iteration [%d].",
                    this, reply, numberOfMessagesSent);
            throw new IllegalStateException(error);
        }
    }
}

class InitiatorPlayer extends Player
{
    private static final String INIT_MESSAGE = "initiator player";

    public InitiatorPlayer(BlockingQueue<String> sent, BlockingQueue<String> received)
    {
        super(sent, received);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        sendInitMessage();
        while (true)
        {
            String receivedMessage = receive();
            reply(receivedMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendInitMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            sent.put(INIT_MESSAGE);
            System.out.printf("Player [%s] sent message [%s].%n", this, INIT_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException interrupted)
        {
            String error = String.format(
                    "Player [%s] failed to sent message [%s].",
                    this, INIT_MESSAGE);
            throw new IllegalStateException(error, interrupted);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4].
Player [Player@69bf9b51] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@712dc5e9] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5].
```

**PS** You may get slightly different output on your machine, like this:

```
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4].
Player [Player@5d7a0209] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5].
Player [InitiatorPlayer@82b9342] sent message [initiator player 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5].
```

This happens because players work in different threads. The following situation is possible:

1. The first player sends message and prints log record to console.
2. The second player receives message and sends reply. But corresponding thread is paused by thread scheduler right after sending the reply.
3. The first player receives reply, sends another one message and prints log record to console.
4. The second player's thread is wake up by thread scheduler and prints log record about his reply mentioned in point #3.

This behavior is correct. Players are synchronized by queues, e.g. the first player will not send new message before answer to previous. But printing logs to console is not synchronized (and must not be) with sending/receiving messages.

**PS2** The task can be solved with only one blocking queue (or even with single mutex). But two separate queues are better for illustration and possible extension of the solution.

Comment: wondering, how to write test cases for initiator and player class provided they are in two different threads